# Keyboard not working but making clicking sounds

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I'm using Asus Vivobook 14. I disabled the touchpad while watching lectures and I think I accidentally turned on filter keys. Because,now none of the keys are working except the power button. But there's this clicking sound whenever I try to use any keys.
How can I make the keys to work again?

I've tried some methods given online. But none of it worked for me. Does anyone have any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which methods have you tried?

Comment: Do you have an external keyboard you can connect to the Asus via USB?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: https://www.alphr.com/windows-log-in-without-keyboard/ then try the stuff below

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two settings in the Windows Settings panel called Sticky keys and Filter keys. These settings might be responsible for this problem with your computer. Therefore, it is better to disable these settings and check if the problem resolves or not. To disable Sticky keys and Filter keys in Windows 11, follow these steps:

1. Select the Start button, then select Settings
2. Switch to the Accessibility tab.
3. Click on the Keyboard menu on the right side.
4. Toggle the Sticky keys and Filter keys button to turn them off.

After that, check if you can type using your keyboard or not.

[image]

---

If that doesn't work, there is an in-built Keyboard Troubleshooter that helps you fix common keyboard-related issues like this one. To run the Keyboard Troubleshooter, follow these steps:

1. Select the Start button, then select Settings
2. Go to System > Troubleshooters.
3. Click on the Other troubleshooters menu.
4. Find the Keyboard Troubleshooter.
5. Click the Run button.
6. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I tried pressing Win+I. But since my touchpad is disabled,I can't even sign in. Because I accidentally put the lap on sleep by clicking power button earlier.

Comment: Thanks. It worked

Comment: @AY Awesome! Enjoy!